# Generate series of 1,1,2,2,3,3,

Tags: programming-languages, series, math

I've an variable as page number (page) whose values increment by one each time. [Page numbering] But, now I need to customize this numbering to 1,1,2,2,3,3..

Can you suggest any formula for generate this kind of series?

**EDIT: (Answer)**

After playing with macros and VBA for some time I've figured out a way to generate this type of series for MS word page numbers. This can be easily done with formulas and {Page} variable in word with formula-

`{=(({PAGE} + MOD({PAGE},2))/2)}`

Comment: What language will you use? There could be simpler / more efficient method other than deriving a formula for the sequence.

Comment: Is this Something like-> If i give `1` the output should be `1,1` if `2` then `1,1,2,2` if `3` then `1,1,2,2,3,3` and so on???

Comment: I use macros in MS WOrd 2007 and outputs shoild be if Page 1 the -> 1, Page 2 -> 1, Page 3-> 2, Page 4->2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with macros and VBA for some time I've figured out a way to generate this type of series for MS word page numbers. This can be easily done with formulas and {Page} variable in word with formula-

`{=(({PAGE} + MOD({PAGE},2))/2)}`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: `(n + 1) / 2`

Answer (score 1):

javascript, adapt to suite:

```
for(i=0; i>yourMaximum; i++){
    WriteSomewhere(i + "," + i);
    if(i != i - yourMaximum)   WriteSomewhere(",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (pages * 2); i++) {
        System.out.println((i / 2) + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is late, but it might help someone.

**A mathematical answer to the problem:**

You do not need to search through all n numbers in order to have a specific result

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . . n

1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 . . . . . . . f(n)

**General formula:**

f(n) = ( n - ( (-1) + (-1)^n )/2 )/2

**Playing with the first (-1) you can shift the results like this:**

f(n) = ( n - ( (**3**) + (-1)^n )/2 )/2

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . . n

0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 . . . . . . . f(n)

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
(int(x/2+1) for x in itertools.count())
```

Comment: you can use integral division `x//2+1` and skip the `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2010/06/21/a-simple-loop)

```
(1..10).map {|n| [n,n]}.flatten
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
```

or

```
(1..10).inject([]) {|m,n| m<<n<<n}
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
```

or

```
(1..10*2).map {|n| (1+n)/2}
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

C#, not a formula but a simplistic algorithm.

```
int[] pages = new int[2*N];
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    page[2*i] = i+1;
    page[2*i+1] = i+2;
}
```